# Chart.js não aparece

Tags: php, chartjs

UPDATE: Agora aparecem as labels e o gráfico exibindo a quantidade, porém todo em cinza com os nomes como `undefined`.

Estou tentando criar um gráfico com o [Chart.js](https://www.chartjs.org/), mas ele não aparece na `div`, ela está em branco. Já havia feito um neste mesmo projeto, mas como eliminei um módulo e respectivamente o BD relativo a ele, precisei criar outro gráfico com outros dados, e agora fica em branco.

Tenho o `Chart.min.js` mais recente instalado.

A função para a geração dos dados é esta:

```
public function getTypeList($id_company){
    $array = array('0'=>0, '1'=>0, '2'=>0, '3'=>0, '4'=>0);
      $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) as total, type FROM inventory WHERE "
            . "id_company = :id_company "
            . "GROUP BY type ORDER BY type ASC";
    $sql = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(':id_company', $id_company);
    $sql->execute();

   if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
        $rows = $sql->fetchAll();

        foreach ($rows as $sale_item){
            $array[$sale_item['type']] = $sale_item['total'];
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

O arquivo `js` do gráfico:

```
var rel2 = new Chart(document.getElementById("rel2"), {
type:'pie',
data:{
    labels: status_name_list,
    datasets: [{
        data: status_list,
        backgroundColor:['#0000FF','#32CD32','#FF0000', '#FFFFFF', '#000000']
    }]
  }
});
```

A chamada na tela:

```
<div class="db-row row2">
  <div class="grid-1">
    <div class="db-info">
      <div class="db-info-title">Tipos de imóveis disponíveis para venda</div>
      <div class="db-info-body" style="height: 300px">
        <canvas id="rel2"></canvas>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

E por fim a chamada no controller:

```
$data['status_list'] = $i->getTypeList($user->getCompany());
```

Não está retornando erros, a `div` onde o gráfico deveria aparecer aparece em branco. Quando dei um `var_dump($rows)` retornou estes dados, mas não sei conferir, sou iniciante. Apareceu realmente o nome dos campos que preciso, (apartamento, etc) mas não sei se está retornando a quantidade corretamente, ou o motivo de não aparecer na tela.

```
array(7) {
  [0]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "4"
    [0]=> string(1) "4"
    ["type"]=> string(11) "Apartamento"
    [1]=> string(11) "Apartamento"
  }
  [1]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(2) "25"
    [0]=> string(2) "25"
    ["type"]=> string(4) "Casa"
    [1]=> string(4) "Casa"
  }
  [2]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "1"
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=> string(19) "Casa em Condomínio"
    [1]=> string(19) "Casa em Condomínio"
  }
  [3]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "2"
    [0]=> string(1) "2"
    ["type"]=> string(9) "Cobertura"
    [1]=> string(9) "Cobertura"
  }
  [4]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "1"
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=> string(4) "cond"
    [1]=> string(4) "cond"
  }
  [5]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "1"
    [0]=> string(1) "1"
    ["type"]=> string(11) "Condomínio"
    [1]=> string(11) "Condomínio"
  }
  [6]=> array(4) {
    ["total"]=> string(1) "3"
    [0]=> string(1) "3"
    ["type"]=> string(4) "Loja"
    [1]=> string(4) "Loja"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que estou vendo, o problema está no `status_name_list`, você não postou como está sendo preenchido esse array, aparece `undefined` quando o chart não encontra o nome da legenda para aquela parte do gráfico.

Então o label teria algo do tipo:

```
labels: ['Apartamento', 'Casa', 'Casa em Condomínio']
```

e aí no data teria os valores:

```
data: [5,10,15]
```

Então o grid lhe traz que para legenda apartamento tem 5 e assim por diante!